# How to properly fund a contract? - Goerli contract funded but chain link transaction fails

Tags: chainlink, goerli

Essentially I'm trying to run the following example from chain link:

https://remix.ethereum.org/#url=https://docs.chain.link/samples/APIRequests/APIConsumer.sol&optimize=false&runs=200&evmVersion=null&version=soljson-v0.8.7+commit.e28d00a7.js

Here is what I did:

1. Selected "Injected Provider - Metamask" as my EVM and deployed the contract to the Goerli test network using my metamask account
2. Downloaded LINK tokens to my metamask account
3. Transferred a total of 35.5 LINK tokens to the newly deployed contract from my Goerli wallet
4. You can see the test contract and validate the tokens here:
   https://goerli.etherscan.io/token/0x326c977e6efc84e512bb9c30f76e30c160ed06fb?a=0x844B94EDfE10102BF6336e08bbFfE7f5fEca285a
5. I'm unable to execute the instructed requestVolume() or any transactions on this contract, even though a transaction cost is supposed to be only 0.1 LINK

Comment: Looks like you accidentally pasted the contract version with Rinkeby params instead of Goerli ones. The docs sample should be fixed now.